# Error Saving the Excel File using worksheet.saveas

Tags: matlab, excel, vba

I have an Excel template file . Based on the Excel version, I would like to SaveAs as Temp.xlsm through Matlab.

Here is the code I am using to save the template file :

```
if(XLversion >= 12.0)
    Workbook = invoke(Excel.Workbooks,'Open',tempxls);
    tempxls1 = [pwd '\utils\temp.xlsm'];
    Workbook.SaveAs(tempxls1,1);
    tempxls = tempxls1;
    extn = 'xlsm';
end
```

The code is working fine. However when I try to open the file, I get the following error :

[image]

However, when the save the temp.xls to temp.xlsm through SaveAs menu, it opens without any error.

Any idea what could be the error in the code or If I am missing something.

Thanks

Comment: `.xlsm` s macro-enabled format. Why don't you try `.xls` or `.xlsx and try opening? The internal structure of office documents changed after Office 2007. So Excel is relying on `extention` to know how the file should be opened.... What's your Excel version?

Comment: Yes, I need a .xlsm format as I have written a number of Macros in the template file.

Comment: What is `MATLAB` tag doing here? :) And what is the version of Excel you are using?

Comment: I am writing an Excel file through `Matlab`. I am using Excel 2007

Comment: Use 52 for your second parameter in saveas... I believe that will resolve the issue

Comment: @DanielCook, Thank you so much for your help. Yes, it did solve the issue. Would you mind converting it to an answer form so that I would help others facing similar issue.

Comment: `52=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled =xlsm` :) [Reference](http://www.rondebruin.nl/saveas.htm)

Comment: Just a quick note, do you really need to open the file and save it, or could you just copy it?

Comment: Yes, We have to. Because we are changing the filetype from *.xls to *.xlsm. Just copy would give an error when you try to open the file ( the same error as in the dialogbox above )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the following code please and comment. You may call this `sub-routine` to save the as the file.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim FileNameVal As String
If SaveAsUI Then
    FileNameVal = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(, "Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm), *.xlsm")
    Cancel = True
    If FileNameVal = "False" Then 'User pressed cancel
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        If Right(ThisWorkbook.Name, 5) <> ".xlsm" Then
            ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FileNameVal & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
        Else
            ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FileNameVal, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
        End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

[Reference:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111491/force-save-as-xlsm-while-maintaining-file-structure)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. However I was looking at a solution in Matlab.

Comment: Glad you worked it out and more thanks to Daniel :) In the code I posted, the `52` file format is already specified if you wish to look into it from VBA one of these days.